# How to use (max-device-width) and (min-device-width) simultaneously in styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, npm, styled-components

```js
const size = {
  mobileS: '320px',
  mobileL: '425px',
}
export const device = {
  mobile: `(min-width: ${size.mobileS}) and (max-width: ${size.mobileL})`,
};
```

I tried to make a custom device and tried to use it but it didn't work..How to use min-width and max-width simultaneously?

Comment: `and tried to use it...` What do you mean by that?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response...btw..I was having some syntax problem in applying media queries using styled-components."and triesd to use it" means applying it in the code...But, now issue is resolved..Thanks, once again..